# NASM Assembly - Get the Result of Multiplying Two Numbers in a Loop

Tags: nasm

I've been trying to the get the result of multiplying 2 numbers in a loop, but I get this error: Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)
I don't know what I'm doing bad, some advice to fix it

```
;nasm 2.13.02           

section .bss
    result:     resb 2
    num1:       resb 2
    num2:       resb 2
    quotient:   resb 2
    remainder:  resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    
    ; setup registers
    ; mul -> AX = (AL * BL = AH AL)  The product is in AX. 
                                    ;High-order 8 bits of the product is stored in AH 
                                    ;and the low-order 8 bits are stored in AL.
    mov [num1], word 0x2A     ;store 42 in num1
    mov [num2], word 0x2B     ;store 43 in num2 (42*43=1806)

    mov al, [num1]
    mov bl, [num2]
    mul bl
    
    mov [result], ax
    
    ;call convert_values
    
    ;----------------------------------
    ; divide by ten
    ; div -> AX = (AX(dividendo) / BL(divisor) = AL (Quotient) AH (Remainder))  
                 ;The dividend is assumed to be in the AX register (16 bits). 
                 ;After division, the quotient goes to the AL register and 
                 ;the remainder goes to the AH register. 

    convert_values:
        xor  ax, ax          ; limpiamos el registro AX = 0
        mov  ax, [result]    
        mov  bl, 10          ; 10
        div  bl              ; divide by 10

        mov  [quotient], al  ; save the Quotient 
                
        call print_char      ;print the latest character
       
        mov ax, [quotient]
        mov [result], ax     ;move new number into result                
        
        or  ax,ax            ;set flags based on ax value
        
        jnz  convert_values  ;while ax != 0 continue process
        ret
    
    ; print a character
    print_char:
        mov [remainder], ah        ; gets the Remainder
        add [remainder], word '0'
        mov eax,4                  ; The system call for write (sys_write)
        mov ebx,1                  ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
        mov ecx,remainder          ; Put the offset of remainder in ecx
        mov edx,1                  ; is a constant, so we don't need to say
        int 80h                    ; Call the kernel
        ret
    ;------------------------------------------------
    
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of your crash, but there is a lot of mixing of byte and word accesses to your variables, that is likely to give you wrong answers after the crash is fixed.  For instance `num1` is one word (two bytes), but since `al` is a byte register, `mov al, [num1]` only loads the low byte of that word.  I'd suggest checking all references to your variables for correct operand size.

Comment: `convert_values` has a `ret` at the end, but it was not called by `call`, so this will jump to a random address off the stack and likely segfault.  Keep track of where control flows, and make sure it ends up at your exit system call (which currently is unreachable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an update, I fixed it. :)

```
;nasm 2.13.02           

section .bss
    result:     resb 2
    num1:       resb 2
    num2:       resb 2
    quotient:   resb 2
    remainder:  resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    
    ; setup registers
    ; mul -> AX = (AX * BX = DX BX)  
                                    ;The multiplicand should be in the AX register, 
                                    ;and the multiplier is a word in memory or another register. 
                                    ;For example, for an instruction like MUL DX, 
                                    ;you must store the multiplier in DX and the multiplicand in AX.

                                    ;The resultant product is a doubleword, which will need 
                                    ;two registers. The high-order (leftmost) portion gets stored 
                                    ;in DX and the lower-order (rightmost) portion gets stored 
                                    ;in AX.
    
    mov [num1], word 0x2A     ;store 42 in eax
    mov [num2], word 0x2B     ;store 43 in edx (42*43=1806)

    mov ax, [num1]
    mov bx, [num2]
    mul bx
    
    mov [result], ax
    
    call convert_values
    
    ;----------------------------------
    ; divide by ten
    ; div -> AX = (AX(dividendo) / BL(divisor) = AL (Quotient) AH (Remainder))  
                 ;The dividend is assumed to be in the AX register (16 bits). 
                 ;After division, the quotient goes to the AL register and 
                 ;the remainder goes to the AH register. 
    convert_values:
        xor  ax, ax           ; clears AX register to `0`
        mov  ax, [result]    
        mov  bl, 10           ; 10
        div  bl               ; divide por 10

        mov  [quotient], al   ; save the Quotient 
                
        call print_char       ;print the latest character
       
        mov  ax, [quotient]   ;move `Quotient` to AX register
        test ax,ax            ;Compares if AX register is equal to `0`
        jz   exit;            ;if flag `ZF` is equal to `1` jump to `exit` label
        
        mov [result], ax      ;moves data from AX register to `result`            
        
        cmp ax,0              ;set flags based on ax value
        
        jnz  convert_values  ;while al != 0 continue process
        ret
    
    ; print a character
    print_char:
        mov [remainder], ah        ; gets the Remainder
        add [remainder], word '0'
        mov eax,4                  ; The system call for write (sys_write)
        mov ebx,1                  ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
        mov ecx,remainder          ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
        mov edx,1                  ; is a constant, so we don't need to say
        int 80h                    ; Call the kernel
        ret
    ;---------------------------------------------
    exit:
        mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
        mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
        int 80h;
```